# Aligning and Registering two point clouds in iOS/ARKit

Tags: swift, opencv, computer-vision, arkit

Does anyone know if there's a native library or API to align two point clouds in Swift/ARKit such as ICP? I know it's possible to do ICP alignment in Python using the Open3D library or OpenCV http://www.open3d.org/docs/release/tutorial/pipelines/icp_registration.html

After reading through Apple's documentation, I see that [VNHomographicImageRegistrationRequest](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/vision/vnhomographicimageregistrationrequest) can be used to find the homography transformation between the current and previous RGB images. However, it wound't consider 3D information like depth maps.

It seems like ARWorldMap would need some sort of similar capability to do feature points tracking and resume the session from the same state later, so I'm curious if anyone knows how it works under the hood.

Another approach I could think of is integrating OpenCV with Swift, but this might have additional complexity, platform compatibility, app size impacts.

If you have any other suggestions, I'd appreciate some pointers. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

There is an Open3d iOS compiled library: https://github.com/kewlbear/Open3D-iOS. Which uses PythonKit as run-time to be executed in the application.

It uses a relatively outdated Open3d version (0.17) and has not been updated in the last few years.

I been using it mostly for Surface creation and PointCloud manipulation, but the same principles should apply for ICP and PointCloud registration.

Comment: Thank you! Were you able to run it in real-time on device? (eg ~30 Hz) os is there some delay especially the mobile compute is not as good as desktop one.

Comment: No. For the moment just post-processing acquired depth point clouds with TrueDepth camera. We think that AR sensors information should be enough (not yet the case for us) to align depth images in real-time.